# Identifying maximised score across an array

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have a sequence of 569 amino acid residues, each given a score. I want to identify a consecutive sequence of 10 such amino acids that maximises the score. Is there an elegant way in which I can do this?

```
amino_acids <- structure(
    list(
        Position=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
        Residue=c("M", "S", "A", "S", "K", "E", "V", "K", "S", "F", "L", "W", "T", "Q", "S", "L", "R", "R", "E", "L"),
        `Bepipred Score`=c(0.565, 0.709, 0.512, 0.516, 0.451, 0.291, -0.11, -0.409, -0.525, -0.548, -0.611, -0.795, -0.825, -0.864, -0.47, -0.387, 0.024, -0.044, -0.209, -0.309)
    ),
    row.names=c(NA, -20L),
    class=c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is the first 20 as an example of the data structure. In this case, sequence 1-10 would be the 'best' followed by 2-11, followed by 3-12 etc.

I have been able to do something similar by chunking the dataframe up into 10 amino acid units and calculating the average but it is clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple moving average, usually used for time series analysis. One way it would be:

```
library(magrittr) ## just for %>% operator
n <- 10
seq <- amino_acids$`Bepipred Score` %>% TTR::SMA(.,n=n) %>% na.omit()
```

Here we have calculated moving averages, and omitted first n-1 values, since they are NA. (you have to have at least n values to calculate average)

```
seq
[1]  0.1452  0.0276 -0.1228 -0.2565 -0.3945 -0.4866 -0.5544 -0.5410 -0.5045 -0.4729 -0.4490
```

Then we simply check which is the highest,

```
## best indexes
(which.max(seq)):(which.max(seq) + n - 1)
[1] 1:10
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do, thanks. For this small example I can see the process. This also makes it fairly simple to extract the n highest averages, so thank you for that.